# Send a post request to a php page using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I'm trying to send a text that is typed via ajax to a php page that will make a query using that text that is received. I want to know how to send the value of variable `nmClient` to the php page. I tried the following code and the return was `500 (Internal Server Error)`. I'm using the framework [Symfony](https://symfony.com/)

Jquery

```
            var name = $("#name").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "../search",
                type: "POST",
                data: {'name':name},
                dataType: "json"

            }).done(function(response) {
                console.log(response);

            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus ) {
                console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus);

            }).always(function() {
                console.log("done");
            });
```

PHP

```
public function searchAction(Request $resquest)
{

    if ($request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        $name = $request->get('name');
        return new JsonResponse(array('name' => $name));
    }

    return new Response('This is not ajax!', 400);
}
```

Comment: `500 (Internal Server Error)` happens on your server... check your php scripts

Comment: also look in your server logs for where the php fails.

Comment: Wrong url `url: "../search",`, try   `url:"{{path('myroutename')}}"` where `myroutename`is the name of the searchAction route

Comment: Parameter `$resquest` should be `$request` in your controller definition

Comment: Use Symfony _profiler to see 500 error details

Comment: Could be wrong but shouldn't your parameter access line be `$request->request->get('name');`? See the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html). The `get()` function is a method of the individual parameter objects (i.e. `query` for _GET_, `request` for _POST_, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to access the parameter `name` in the incorrect place. The `get()` method is available on the `ParameterBag` instance, not the `Request` instance. Try the following:

```
$name = $request->request->get('name');
```

Per the docs [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html):

> Each property is a ParameterBag instance (or a sub-class of), which is a data holder class:
>
> - request: ParameterBag;
> - query:  ParameterBag;
> - cookies: ParameterBag;
> - attributes: ParameterBag;
> - files:  FileBag;
> - server:  ServerBag;
> - headers: HeaderBag.
>
> All ParameterBag instances have methods to retrieve and update their data:
>
> - get() Returns a parameter by name.

Here is the example from that same page:

```
// the query string is '?foo[bar]=baz'   
$request->query->get('foo');
```

In the docs example case, the parameters are passed via the *GET* method as a query string but they access them via the `query` `ParameterBag` instance. You'll want to use the `request` `Parameter Bag` instance since your parameters are passed via the *POST* method.